# Upload Picture in Android to MySQL database

Tags: php, android, mysql

I currently develop a registration form with profile picture. The user need to browse the picture from gallery and select one from there as profile picture. After that, the user will submit the form through HTTP post to insert the whole information into MySQL database using PHP script.

Now, I facing problem in create a form to upload the picture in my android emulator. I co not know how to create one.

Currently, I using SDK 10 for android version 2.3.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this tutorial. It will help you: http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/04/25/android-upload-an-image-to-a-server/